# ¿Cómo se ordena de forma eficiente un array en pantalla?

Tags: java, array

Mi nueva consulta es si hay una forma eficiente de ordenar los valores almacenados en un array. Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de programación en el cuál debo hacer un menú y necesito ordenar los valores de un array. Ya descubrí como ordenarlos, pero el método que usé no es eficiente ya que requiere bastantes líneas de código y cambia de posición los valores en el array lo que provoca que tenga que escribir más código para cambiar de posición todos los demás array int y String. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que el array se muestre ordenado de menor a mayor o mayor a menor sin que los valores cambien de posición?

Comment: Podrias mirar el [tour] y tambien [ask]. Tu pregunta wa poxo clara.. si no lo ordenas como lo vas a mostrar ordenado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El objeto Array tiene su metodo sort

```
Arrays.sort(array);
// Ordenado de mayor a menor
Arrays.sort(array, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: Sergestux gracias por ayudar pero el método no me funciona.

Comment: ¿Querías decir "la clase Arrays" en vez de el objeto Array no?